# Ignoring escape characters in python

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I am trying to insert a title into a DB.  Sometimes the title has quotes and it throws an error.

I can't replace quotes with a \" because it thinks that I am escaping the quote.

```
sql = 'UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="{}";'

title = 'A "Title" With Quotes'

sql.format(title.replace('"','\"'))
```

This replaces the quotes with more quotes so it changes nothing.

```
'UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="A "Title" With Quotes";'
```

If I try to escape the backslash it doesn't escape anything.

```
sql.format(title.replace('"','\\"'))

'UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="A \\"Title\\" With Quotes";'
```

Comment: You should use query parameters instead of trying to glue values into your SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is using triple quotes, that's interprets text inside as a string:

```
sql = """UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="{}";"""
```

you either can format It was you want:

```
sql = """UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="{}";""".format('A \\"B\\"')
print(sql)
```

output:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="A \"B\"";
```

Works on MySQL

Comment: sql = """UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="{}";""".format('A "Title" With Quotes')


'UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="A "Title" With Quotes";'


Invalid sql

Comment: This is my output: UPDATE `table_name` SET `title`="A \\"B\\"";

Comment: @ChadSkiles It's not what I got using python 3.7
See here https://repl.it/repls/WoefulEntireVirtualmachines

Comment: That's odd.  I doesn't work in IDLE, but it works everywhere else.